# ORMLite - update without null values

Tags: java, android, sqlite, ormlite

I want to update a record in my SQLite DB. This record is stored in a table with fields described by annotation `@DatabaseField(canBeNull = false)`. Firstly I store a record, I fill all required values and later I try to update it.
I want to update only some values of record. For example:

```
Order o = new Order();
o.setStatus(OrderStatus.PENDING);
o.setIdOrder(1);

orderDAO.update(order);
```

I use `update` method of `RuntimeExceptionDao`. It constructs full update query with all columns.

For example:

```
UPDATE `order` SET `idCustomer` = ?, `number` = ?, `orderDate` = ?, `status` = ? WHERE `idOrder` = ?
```

And it throws me the exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Unable to run update stmt on object Order
```

How can I specify fields for `UPDATE` query? I want only this query

```
UPDATE `order` SET `status` = ? WHERE `idOrder` = ?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default `dao.update(...)` updates all fields.  It doesn't know that you've only changed a couple of them or anything.

Typically you request the item from the database, change it and call `dao.update(...)`:

```
Order order = orderDao.queryForId(1);
if (order.getStatus() != OrderStatus.PENDING) {
   order.setStatus(OrderStatus.PENDING);
   orderDao.update(order);
}
```

This allows you to test the current `Order` status, etc..  If you must create a custom `UPDATE` method, you can use the `UpdateBuilder`:

> http://ormlite.com/docs/update-builder

For example:

```
UpdateBuilder<Order, Integer> updateBuilder = orderDAO.updateBuilder();
updateBuilder.updateColumnValue(Order.STATUS_FIELD_NAME, OrderStatus.PENDING);
updateBuilder.where().eq(Order.ID_FIELD_NAME, 1);
updateBuilder.update();
```

Comment: thank you. Is possible also update non-primitive type (foreign) with `updateColumnValue()`?

Comment: You can only update the id of the corresponding foreign object.  That is all that is stored in the `Order` table @misco.